# Max date value on NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, key-value-coding

I am rather confused about key-value-coding and core data.

The Apple docs show making this call

```
NSDate *latestDate = [transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@max.date"];
```

but when I add it to my own class, I get this exception

```
Exception [<MyClass 0x171be8>  valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key @max.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the name of your `NSDate` property?

Comment: That specific expression only works on a collection object, since it's querying the objects in itself to find the maximum value for the specified key path. You should be using `NSFetchRequest` with an `NSPredicate` to fetch objects from your backing persistent store using this criteria.

Comment: Working off of what I said above, the reason why you're getting that error is because instances of `NSManagedObject` (or any non-collection object) don't know how to deal with a predicate expression such as `"@max"` when given to `-valueForKeyPath:` - only collections do.

Comment: Ah, okay. I have been running that code against an instance, not a collection. I read it was magical, but it's not that magical :) So I still need to write an NSFetchRequest and NSPredicate type code block after all.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your `Transaction` entity (or whatever the entity contained in `transactions` is) has a date attribute with a different name or type.

Please check the data model and your `NSManagedObject` subclass to make sure it is indeed `date` and of type "Date"(data model) and "NSDate" (subclass).

Comment: The "transaction" object came from Apple documentation. My date field is called "modified". Its looking like the @max operator is only known to a collection and not an instance.

Comment: Of course. It says transaction**s**, indicating an array or set. So, having a collection of your entity objects, `valueForKeyPath:@"@max.modified"` should work.